# Where's FrameworkPropertyMetadata in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

And/Or how do I define a `DependencyProperty` on my control that sepcifies `AffectsMeasure`?

EDIT: oh, just saw this - do I have to call `InvalidateMeasure` on `this` in the propertychangedhandler?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. For UWP [AffectsMeasure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx) is not supported. For Framework 3+ it works. For default UWP binding I am working with CodeSnipped functionality. WIth the eventhandling you can act transparent. The result of my codeSnippet for UWP looks like this for my Model:

```
    #region IsSelected

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(PositionModel),
            new PropertyMetadata((bool)false,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsSelectedChanged)));

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PositionModel target = (PositionModel)d;
        bool oldIsSelected = (bool)e.OldValue;
        bool newIsSelected = target.IsSelected;
        target.OnIsSelectedChanged(oldIsSelected, newIsSelected);
    }

    protected virtual void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool oldIsSelected, bool newIsSelected)
    {
       // Do what your need in your property changed event
       // In my case, I just raise the PropertyChanged for PropertyChangedEventHandler
       // RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
    }
    #endregion
```

XAML:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" Visibility="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
```

Windows 10, Store, VS 2017, 
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Version 5.2.3

Comment: I'm not sure you have posted this answer to the correct question... did you read further than _how do I define a DependencyProperty_ ?

Comment: Sorry. For UWP AffectsMeasure is not supported. For Framework 3+ it works. Just replace `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` by `PropertyMetadata` and use namespace `namespace Windows.UI.Xaml` in your ViewModel. As I understood, that will exact solve your problem and answer your question.

Comment: Well, that is as much information as I posted in my question. And no, my question is not solved. If you read carefully I want a dependency property that triggers a new measuring pass. Because that's what `InvalidateMeasure` did. Your example triggers a new measuring pass because the Binding goes to Visibility. Try `Tag` and tell me it just works.